# How to set "limited access" permission level to user/group

Tags: permissions

Im trying to give user/group "limited access", but following [these "instructions"](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Permission-levels-and-permissions-49d456eb-d3c8-4402-86b1-deb911224afb). The article says that if you give a user/group access to an item (like a list) the users automatically get "limited access" to the site where the list is.

I dont get that result. When I "check permissions" I get all users to have "None" as permission level.

The users can get to my list but not to anything else, which is what I want.

Comment: What would users be allowed to see of the site?

Comment: Hi Jan. They should see just one page in the Pages-library (the "public page"), and nothing else. Any other solution to achive the same goal is also welcome :o)

Comment: You shouldn't strive to grant `Limited Access` to a group, SP will add it as needed.

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar problem and solved it for us by:

1. Deactivate the Site Collection Feature: "Limited-access user permission lockdown mode"
2. Re-assign the permission for the user.
3. Let him/her try again.

[[Breaking permission inheritence does not set 'Limited Access'](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/193769/breaking-permission-inheritence-does-not-set-limited-access])